# Invoke function on specific element load

Tags: javascript

I want to submit a form when it's loaded, without waiting for page full load (it takes very long).
Here's my code, it's not good, I know... but I can't think of anything else.

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("redirect");

while(!element) {
    element = document.getElementsByName("redirect");
};

element[0].form.submit();
```

Is there a better way to detect if this form element is loaded?

Comment: `while(!element[0])` it should be... hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery DOM ready(only DOM, not waiting for load images and other resourses):

```
$(function(){
  var element = document.getElementsByName("redirect");
  element[0].form.submit();
})
```

Or without DOM ready event. You can use recursion;

```
function checkFormExist(){
  var element = document.getElementsByName("redirect");
  if(element[0] && element[0].form){
    element[0].form.submit();
   } else {
   setTimeout(checkFormExist, 300);//repeat check after 0.3 seconds
  }
}
checkFormExist()
```

Not so beautiful, but better than while-loop.

Comment: Thanks for second one, definitely better than while loop :D solved

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the element, you should be able to set the `onload` attribute to a javascript callback. For example:

```
<form id="submit_me_when_i_load" onload="submit_form">
...
</form>
```

Then write a java script function above it somewhere, `function submit_form(){}`.

Comment: input is on another website, I'm trying to write an Userscript for my tampermonkey :)